# Center Table via Header passed to PowerShell ConvertTo-HTML Command?

Tags: html, css, powershell, format, powershell-3.0

I'm converting a CSV to an HTML Page in my PowerShell script using the ConvertTo-HTML command. The output is great, except that the table after being converted is left-aligned (blacked out company specific information and logos).

Image Link Showing Current Output - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIdo.png

I can't figure out how to get it to center the table itself using only the header. For reference, here's my header code. I'm not familiar with CSS/HTML to begin with, and all of the information I'm finding is around using the  tag, which I really can't use since I'm defining the body via the ConvertTo-HTML command dynamically.

```
$Header = @"
<img align="left" src="IMAGELINK" alt="WEBSITE" width="355" height="133">
<img align="right" src="IMAGELINK" alt="WEBSITE">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #F15C22;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; nth-child(even): #f2f2f2;}
</style>
"@
```

Comment: Try `<style>TABLE{margin: auto;...`

Comment: Wow, it was that simple. That was it, thanks!